# How to select Symbols in watchlist using Pine script

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to loop through tradingview watchlist symbols using pine script, is there any api that can give this info?
i searched and i could not find a way yet, is the answer in this link [link](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/) is up to date ??

regards.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, looping through symbols is not supported

Workaround is that you can apply alerts to them all individually and let the api handle all the signals created or you open the chart manually

Answer (score 0):

With а `security` function, you can check up to 40 symbols for your parameters in a single study and display them as a label.